# character not rotating with the direction of acceleration even though i turned on Orient Rotation To Movement - in unreal engine 4

Tags: unreal-engine4

```
bUseControllerRotationPitch = false;
bUseControllerRotationYaw = false;
bUseControllerRotationRoll = false;

//will let the character face the direction of acceleration/movement
GetCharacterMovement()->bOrientRotationToMovement = true;
```

when I compile it and run the program in ue4 it somehow doesn't rotate my character to the direction of acceleration does anyone know why? checked the character movement and orient rotation to movement is ticked, can't really seem to find use controller rotation yaw though, am I supposed to manually uncheck one of them or something?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody still wondering in my case the problem was that
`UCharacterMovementComponent::RotationRate` was only zero initialized.

Answer (score 0):

```
bUseControllerRotationPitch = false;
bUseControllerRotationYaw = true;
bUseControllerRotationRoll = false;

//will let the character face the direction of acceleration/movement
GetCharacterMovement()->bOrientRotationToMovement = true;
```

Try the above code once. I think the rotation problem will get rid.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).